# Spring Cache -- can't to get a list of data

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I can't to get list of data through ehcache.

**servlet-context:**

```
<cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
    p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache"/>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
      p:configLocation="/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/ehcache.xml" p:shared="true" />
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
<cache name="category"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
       eternal="false"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
       timeToIdleSeconds="200"
       timeToLiveSeconds="500"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>
```

I have an entity of Category:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long categoryId;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

private long level;
private long parentId;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "categories")
private Set<Post> posts;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;

public Category() {
}

public Category(User user, long level, String name, long parentId) {
this.user = user;
this.level = level;
this.name = name;
this.parentId = parentId;
}
// ...
}
```

Then, I try to cache this methods:

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {
@Resource
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@Override
@CachePut(value = "category", key = "#category.categoryId")
public Category add(Category category) {
    return categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(category);
}

@Override
@Cacheable("category")
public Category findById(long id) {
    return categoryRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
@Cacheable("category")
public Category findByParentIdThroughCategoryId(long prntId, long userId) {
    return categoryRepository.findByParentIdThroughCategoryId(prntId, userId);
}

@Override
@Cacheable("category")
public List<Category> findByParentId(long prntId, long userId) {
    return categoryRepository.findByParentId(prntId, userId);
}

@Override
@Cacheable("category")
public List<Category> findAll(long userId) {
    return categoryRepository.findAll(userId);
}

@Override
@CacheEvict("category")
public void remove(long id) {
    categoryRepository.delete(id);
}
}
```

When adding a category, and then try to bring it to view all categories that have user findByParentId/findall, it returns an empty list

> []

It has something to do that for example I cache the categories, and then take the list of categories, I tried to get the category with ID 11 -- findById, and found:

> ru.mrchebik.model.Category@f0b8277

Comment: Please confirm first that `categoryRepository.findAll(userId)` and `categoryRepository.findByParentId(prntId, userId)` are returning something when called directly. Another unrelated comment is that your `CategoryServiceImpl` class should not be annotated with `@Repository`, only your `CategoryRepository` should.

Comment: This methods are returning values. If it wasn't successful, I would not do caching.

Hmm... I always do this @Repository and all works. I moved `@Repository` to `CategoryRepository`, thanks.

Comment: @artemisian I also try to do this: `@Cacheable(cacheNames = "category", key = "#userId")` but it changed nothing

Comment: By any chance do you have a userId and a categoryId with the same value? Please replace the Cacheable annotation of findAll by `@Cacheable(cacheNames = "category", key = "'findAll-'.concat(#userId"))"` and try again.

Comment: sorry there is a typo, should be `@Cacheable(cacheNames = "category", key = "'findAll-'.concat(#userId)"`

Comment: I still get the empty list

Comment: the problem was in setting ehcache. I change `timeToIdleSeconds="200"
       timeToLiveSeconds="500"` to `timeToIdleSeconds="0"
       timeToLiveSeconds="10"` and after some time, categories added to the cache

Comment: Can you add the ehcache and spring versions used?

Comment: @LouisJacomet of course, ehcache is 2.10.3 and spring are 4.3.4 (spring security - 4.2.1)

Answer (score 2):

Your setup has a number of problems both at Ehcache and Spring levels.

For Ehcache, you should not have a smaller disk size than the heap size. For a while now the tiering model in ehcache means that all entries must be in the disk tier, so you are effectively artificially constraining the heap size to the disk size with this setup.

On the Spring side, you are using a single cache to hold different things, but they will conflict.

- Your `@CachePut` will store a single category, mapped to a `long` key which matches what your `@Cacheable` on `findById` does.
- However, this will conflict with the `@Cacheable` on `findAll` which also uses a `long` as the key but caches a `List<Category>`. So any collision between `userId` and `categoryId` can cause unexpected class cast exceptions in client code - expecting a `List` getting a `Category` or the opposite.
- Finally you have two methods which take two `long` as parameters but do a different service call while the caching is configured the same. And that service call returns again disjoint types - `List<Category>` and `Category`. Which will cause similar issues as in the previous point.

Also, I am under the impression that you expect single entry caching to magically append entries to matching lists. This is not going to happen.

I strongly recommend reviewing your caching needs and better understand what the Spring abstraction offers ... and what it does not.

Comment: thank you, I removed some cacheable elements, and left 2: `findByParentId` and `findAll`. So, I added keys: `'findByParrentId-' + #category.parentId + ',' + #category.user.userId"` and `'findAll-' + #category.user.userId`. How you say, I get an exception about `ClassCastException: ru.mrchebik.model.Category cannot be cast to java.util.List`. Can you to help me, how I can to fix this?

Comment: Without the stack trace, hard to say. Might require a separate question though.

Comment: So that stack trace is effectively the issue I mentioned in my original answer. Make sure your changes have been applied and the cache is cleared.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand what I need to do